# Wordpress 6.2.2: Using relative URLs in a multisite setup

Tags: php, wordpress, function, url

I want to use relative URLS in a multisite setup.
Use case as follows

the main site is **xyz.com**

the sub sites are **xyz.com/jp, xyz.com/uk, xyz.com/ca**

I use the relative link **/puzzle/**

when I use it for example on the subsite xyz.com/jp

it goes to **xyz.com/puzzle**

instead of **xyz.com/jp/puzzle**

How can I get it to go to the subsite instead of the main site?

Answer (score 0):

I used this code in the functions file and it seems to work.

```
add_filter('the_content', 'custom_modify_content_links');
function custom_modify_content_links($content) {
    $current_path = parse_url($current_site->path, PHP_URL_PATH);
    $current_url = untrailingslashit(home_url($current_path));

    $pattern = '#(<a\s+[^>]*href=[\'"])/([^\'"/][^\'"]*)([\'"][^>]*>)#i';
    $replacement = '$1' . trailingslashit($current_url) . '$2$3';
    $content = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $content);

    return $content;
}
```